# fatal: [212.117.31.141]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (file.jar): Not a directory"}

Tags: ansible, configuration-management

Can't copy files ,because I get this error "Not a directory"

```
- name: Copy file with owner and permissions
  copy:
    src: files/
    dest: /opt/day/scripts
    owner: author
    group: aem
    mode: '0744'
    force: yes
```

What could be the cause of that?
What does that mean?

Comment: does the destination directory (/opt/day/scripts) exist on the remote server ?  also does the owner (author) and group (aem) exist on the remote server ?

Comment: yes, it exists there and that is the correct user/group

Comment: Does the files folder contain multiple files? In that case you should consider using ‘with_items’ to iterate over multiple files. If you want i can give a proper example of this.

Comment: It has a lot of files.

Comment: But I need whatever files there are. I don't want to specify each file

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Also there are folders too, not only files

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file in templates directory and Consider using the following ansible module

```yaml
- name: transfer the scripts
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ destination_dir_path }}/{{ item | basename }}"
    mode: 0777
    owner: author
    group: aem
  with_fileglob:
    - templates/*.*
```

- Directory structure of role

```sh
$ ls 
ls
defaults  tasks  templates
```

- You would need to copy the files to the template directory. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Doesn't fileglob copy only files, without folders?

Comment: yes,but also [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) copies the files from local to remote machines. If you want directories to be created, then consider using [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html) module